# Unity3D why multiply axis with SPEED?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im pretty new in programming in Unity...

So my question is:

Why you multiply the

```
Input.GetAxis("VertOrHorz") * speed
```

with speed. Because I was used to move things with the += or -= operator.

Could anyone please do me a favour and explain it to me :).

Thanks in advance

Jakob

Comment: Did you read this in a tutorial somewhere? `Input.GetAxis()` gives you a value in the range of [-1, 1]. Multiplying it by speed just changes its magnitude, so the line you've given will produce a number in the range of [speed, -speed]. With this new number, you could use it in conjunction with `Transform.Translate()`, `Rigidbody.MovePosition()`, etc. Perhaps you may need to reread wherever you read this so you have an in-context explanation? Because can't give the definite reason why the author did this, just speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) function returns values from `-1f` to `1f` or `0f` to `1f`. This value range is so little to the extent that it cannot move an Object.

For example, adding force to a `Rigidbody` with a value of `0.5f` returned from `Input.GetAxis` wont be able to do anything.

By multiplying it with another number(`speed`), you will be able to get a number big enough to actually move the Object.

If you are doing anything that requires a number between `-1f` to `1f` or `0f` to `1f`, then you do **not** need to multiply the value from the [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) function with any other number.